# Updating a row by rowid in oracle using spring-jdbc

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc

I have a weird problem updating a row by rowid in oracle using spring-jdbc.
The problem is that everything is ok but for some rowids the update will never be done and 
application is frozen.
I changed spring log level to DEBUG to see what's happening but nothing's strange and spring log is exactly as successful updates.

I tried to execute the same sql in plsql and the update was executed successfully.

spring version is 3.1.1.RELEASE
oracle version is 11.1.0.6.0

body of update method in dao is:

String sql=
 
"UPDATE "+schema+".MSG m SET m.STATE="+state+" WHERE ROWID='"+msg.getRowId()+"'";
getJdbcTemplate().update(sql);

dao bean:

```
<bean id="messageDao" class="com.foo.dao.springjdbc.MessageDaoSpringJdbcImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

jdbcTemplate:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

data source:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.ip}:${db.port}:${db.sid}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

any idea?

Comment: When your app is running, is it possible that the row in question could be locked by some other activity in the database?  For example, if the row was read by some other application or tool, and the resulting transaction was not committed or rolled back, the row would be locked.  Then, if your app tried to update the row it might freeze.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to figure it out. thanks bob